# How to confgure the PGProperty TCP_KEEP_ALIVE that is available at HikariConfig

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hikaricp

How do I configure the property value that tcpkeepalive value is set to true?

I already tried

```
spring:
  datasource:
    connection-properties: tcpKeepAlive=true
    connectionproperties: tcpKeepAlive=true
```

However, without success.

HikariConfig does contain a Properties object, but how has the values be defined in the yml file that they are loaded there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this property is a connection property of the driver, you need to configure the `dataSourceProperties` property on `hikari`. You can do this like:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      data-source-properties:
        tcpKeepAlive: true
```

Alternatively, you could include the properties in the `spring.datasource.url` property.

Comment: thanks, your first suggestion has worked. i also tried the url property but it hasn't worked. is the format of "url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5430/postgres;tcpKeepAlive=true" correct?

Comment: @sge No, it would be `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5430/postgres?tcpKeepAlive=true`, see also https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html

Comment: it works with url parameter as well (yaml properties and url properties can not be mixed). url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5430/postgres?username=postgres&password=postgres&tcpKeepAlive=true